# What is an anti-pattern?

Tags: mobile, selection, anti-patterns, material-design

> "Using checkboxes (or custom analogs) to initiate selection is an explicit anti-pattern for mobile."

What does Google mean by anti-pattern?

Source: http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/selection.html

Comment: *About making questions on this site:
Search, and research
**Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself**, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!.*   
**It's clear not a single try of search has been made.**

Comment: @rewobs I did Google it first but I admit I must not have been paying attention, because the answer is right there. However, the top results are typically about social and software (programming) anti-patterns, so I think an answer from the UX community is still valuable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An anti-pattern is much like a regular design pattern in that it is a common solution to a general problem. The difference is that an anti-pattern is a **bad** solution to the problem.